# Is Backbone.js Collection Refresh method still available?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

The `refresh` method on the Collection class is documented here:
http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-refresh

Yet, when I call the method, I get "is not a function" error.
Also, looking at the DOM w/ Firebug, the `refresh` method is not present on my Collection.
Even looking through the backbone.js source, I see no definition of a `refresh` method.

Is the `refresh` method still available?
If not, why was it removed?
How do I update the collection in bulk?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `.refresh` on an instance of a Collection.

```
var Col = Backbone.Collection.extend({ ... });
Col.refresh(); // INVALID
(new Col).refresh(); // VALID
```

[`.refresh` source code](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-60)

If your looking at the latest source code on the master branch then it's been renamed to reset. Please use the latest stable version. When the release the new stable version (0.3.4) They will update the documentation to mention reset

Comment: It exists in [0.3.3](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/0.3.3/backbone.js) just not in the latest master. Probably a merge that went wrong.

Comment: It's been renamed to reset. Please use the latest stable version. When the release the new stable version (0.3.4) They will update the documentation to mention reset.